# Getting a NameError (undefined local variable or method `“_”')

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to initialize a collection through

```
 c = Collection.new(name: current_user.account.name + "_" + @form.form_name, description: @form.form_name,account: @form.account, data_types: columns, formats: columns)
```

The thing is that this works locally but on production I get this error

```
NameError (undefined local variable or method `“_”' for #<FormsController:0x0000001007a890>):
```

I have been trying to figure this out for the past couple of hours but to no avail

Answer (score 3):

You're using the wrong kind of inverted commas in your source code. Check the difference between `"` and `“`. They look similar but Ruby only uses the first type to denote a string – the second type is interpreted like any other character, so ruby thinks you are trying to add a variable called `“_”` to your string, and then throws this error telling you that the variable it thinks you are trying to use doesn't exist.

This can often happen if you have copied code from somewhere else (like a tutorial website) and pasted it in, as sometimes the wrong character will have been used to display the tutorial or whatever it is.

It also sometimes comes about if you are using an editor not primarily designed for writing code, as some of them automatically replace `"` with `“` at the beginning and `”` at the end, which looks lovely when you're writing reported speech, but breaks code!

---

On a side-note, a more ruby-ish way of writing

```
current_user.account.name + "_" + @form.form_name
```

would be to use string interpolation, like so:

```
"#{current_user.account.name}_#{@form.form_name}"
```

The `'string' + 'string'` format is totally valid syntax, but string interpolation is usually more readable, less prone to errors, and recommended by the [ruby style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#string-interpolation). As @sawa pointed out below, it is also more efficient in terms of the computing resources it uses.

Comment: It is also more economic. The one with `+` creates temporal substrings, and then immediately throws away.